# Редирект после обработки шаблонизатором

Tags: php, редирект, шаблонизаторы

Использую шаблонизатор [XTemplate](http://phpxtemplate.org/) (2007 год).

Старенький, но работу свою делает на совесть)

Проблема в том, что после парсинга он выдаёт готовый результат и выводит его в браузере. Хочется обойти проблему повторной отправки сообщения при обновлении страницы. Редирект прикрутить не получается.

Суть: после ввода логина/пароля в случае ошибки происходит открытие этой же страницы с выводом сообщения об ошибке. При нажатии на F5 либо обновление страницы - происходит повторная отправка формы.

Контроллер:

```
$xtpl = new XTemplate('main.html', ROOT . '/views/');
$xtpl->array_loop( 'page.authorization.i', 'error', $errors );
$xtpl->assign('p', $p);
$xtpl->parse('page.authorization');
$xtpl->parse('page');
$xtpl->out('page');
```

html:

```
        <!-- BEGIN: page -->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Авторизация пользователя</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        </head>
        <body>
    <!-- BEGIN: authorization -->
        <h1>Вход</h1>
        <!-- BEGIN: i -->
        <p>{error}</p>
        <!-- END: i -->
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div>
                <label for="login">Логин:</label>
                <input type="text" name="login" id="login" value="{p.login}">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="password">Пароль:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="{p.password}">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Войти">
            </div>
        </form>
        <!-- END: authorization -->
    </body>
</html>
<!-- END: page -->
```

[Сам XTemplate](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xtpl/files/XTemplate%20PHP5/0.4.0/XTemplate-0.4.0.zip/download)

Функция out:

```
public function out ($bname) {
        $out = $this->text($bname);
        echo $out;
    }
```

Может есть какой параметр header чтобы в него впихнуть результат шаблонизатора и открыть страницу с этими данными?

Comment: я что-то не совсем понял, в чем проблема,и при чем тут шаблонизатор? Я так понимаю загвоздка в том, что вы отправляете форму с post-запросом. Получаете ответ. Жмете ф5, а браузер вам говорит типа _"страница устарела, отправить данные еще раз?"_.  Это обычное поведение при post-запросе. Поэтому поясните, при чем тут шаблонизатор вообще.

Comment: чтобы от этого избавиться надо после неудачно авторизации сделать редирект на get-метод. Но тут вам придется ошибки логина сохранять в сессию и все такое. Так обычно никто не делает. Либо еще авторизацию вообще можно через ajax-сделать.

Comment: Поясняю: отправляю со страницы POST запрос. В контроллере обрабатываю его и вызываю для вывода обработанного результата шаблонизатор, который выводит через echo результат. Проблема в том, что если нажать на F5 (ну обновить страницу), то браузер выдаёт: "Чтобы отобразить эту страницу, Firefox должен отправить информацию, которая повторит любое ранее произведённое действие (например, запрос на поиск или онлайн-покупка)."

Comment: А так, можно было бы через редирект сделать без повторной отправки...